# Scopes in Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I probably missed something, but I thought Scopes like  @Singleton are used to define "scoped lifecycles".

I use Dagger 2 in an Android app (but I don't think the problem is android related at all).

I have 1 Module:

```
@Module public class MailModule {

  @Singleton @Provides public AccountManager providesAccountManager() {
    return new AccountManager();
  }

  @Singleton @Provides public MailProvider providesMailProvider(AccountManager accountManager) {
    return new MailProvider(accountManager);
  }
}
```

I have two different components with `@Singleton` scope:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = MailModule.class)
public interface LoginComponent {

  public LoginPresenter presenter();
}


@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = MailModule.class
)
public interface MenuComponent {

  MenuPresenter presenter();

}
```

Both, `MenuPresenter` and `LoginPresenter`, have an `@Inject` constructor. While MenuPresenter expects `MailProvider` as parameter, LoginPresenter takes an `AccountManager`:

```
  @Inject public MenuPresenter(MailProvider mailProvider) { ... }

  @Inject public LoginPresenter(AccountManager accountManager) { ... }
```

But every time I use the components to create a `MenuPresenter` or `LoginPresenter` I get a fresh new instance of `MailProvider` and `AccountManager`. I thought they were in the same scope and should therefore be kind of singleton (in the same scope).

Did I understand something completely wrong. How do I define a real singleton for multiple components in dagger 2?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I assume that `LoginComponent` and `MenuComponent` are used separately, e.g. in `LoginActivity` and `MenuActivity`. Each component is built in `Activity.onCreate`. If so, components are recreated every time new activity created, modules and dependencies too, independent of what scope they bond to. Therefore, you get new instances of `MainProvider` and `AccountManager` every time.

`MenuActivity` and `LoginActivity` have separate livecycles, so dependencies from `MailModule` cannot be singleton in both of them. What you need is to declare root component with `@Singleton` scope (e.g. in Application subclass), make `MenuComponent` and `LoginComponent` depend on it. Activity level component cannot be @Singleton scoped, better to create your own scopes using `@Scope` annotation, e.g.:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Scope
public @interface MenuScope {
}
```

Or you can leave them unscoped.

Regarding scopes at all here's brief from initial [Dagger 2 proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fwg-NsMKYtYxeEWe82rISIHjNrtdqonfiHgp8-PQ7m8/edit#heading=h.5xwubel5z6iq):

> ```
> @Singleton
> @Component(modules = {…})
> public interface ApplicationComponent {}
> ```
>
> That declaration enables dagger to enforce the following constraints:
>
> - A given component may only have bindings (including scope annotations on classes) that are unscoped or of the declared scope.
>     I.e. a component cannot represent two scopes.  When no scope is
>     listed, bindings may only be unscoped.
> - A scoped component may only have one scoped dependency.  This is the mechanism that enforces that two components don’t each declare their
>     own scoped binding.  E.g. Two Singleton components that each have
>     their own @Singleton Cache would be broken.
> - The scope for a component must not appear in any of its transitive dependencies.  E.g.: SessionScoped -> RequestScoped -> SessionScoped
>     doesn’t make any sense and is a bug.
> - @Singleton is treated specially in that it cannot have any scoped dependencies.  Everyone expects Singleton to be the “root”.
>
> The goal of this combination of rules is to enforce that when scope is
>   applied, components are composed with the same structure that we used
>   to have with Dagger 1.0 plus()’d ObjectGraphs, but with the ability to
>   have static knowledge of all of the bindings and their scopes.  To put
>   it another way, when scopes are applied, this limits the graphs than
>   can be built to only those that can be correctly constructed.

From my own practice, it's clearer not to use `@Singleton` at all. Instead of that, I use `@ApplicationScope`. It serves to define singletons on whole application and does not have additional restrictions as `@Singleton` has.

Hope that helps you :). It's quite tricky to be understood quickly, takes time, for me at least it was.

Comment: But a component can only have one Scope annotation, right? How would I do that if I have an application component with `@Application` and LoginComponent with `@Activity` scope?

Comment: Right. Component cannot be annotated with two scopes. Activity scope component would have all dependencies from application scope component if it is defined in annotation `@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)`. Think of components with scopes as graphs and subgraphs. Application component and its scope - root graph, activity component and its scope - root's subgraph.

Comment: Does avoiding usage of ```@Singleton``` scope allow to inject ```@Application``` dependencies into ```@Activity``` scope? Example would be, if MyPresenter is of ```@Application``` scope and I want to inject it into MyActivity which is of ```@Activity``` scope.

Comment: @AAverin it is. But I think it can be achieved by using `@Singleton` too.

Comment: This is by far the best explanation I have found !! +1

Comment: "@Singleton is treated specially in that it cannot have any scoped dependencies. Everyone expects Singleton to be the “root"
Does Dagger 2 actually enforce this?

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following to define a real singleton for multiple components. I am assuming `@ApplicationScoped` and `@ActivityScoped` to be the different scopes.

```
@Module public class MailModule {
  @Provides @ApplicationScoped 
  public AccountManager providesAccountManager() {
    return new AccountManager();
  }

  @Provides @ApplicationScoped
  public MailProvider providesMailProvider(AccountManager accountManager) {
        return new MailProvider(accountManager);
  }
}
```

Then a `MailComponent` can be defined for the `MailModule`. The `LoginComponent` and `MenuComponent` can depend on the `MailComponent`.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Component(modules = MailModule.class)
public interface MailComponent {
  MailProvider mailProvider();
  AccountManager accountManager();
}

@ActivityScoped
@Component(dependencies = MailComponent.class)
public interface LoginComponent {
  LoginPresenter presenter();
}

@ActivityScoped
@Component(dependencies = MailComponent.class)
public interface MenuComponent {
  MenuPresenter presenter();
}
```

The `MailComponent` can be initialized as shown below and can be used in `MenuComponent` and `LoginComponent` again shown below.

```
MailComponent mailComponent = DaggerMailComponent.builder().build();

DaggerMenuComponent.builder().mailComponent(mailComponent).build();

DaggerLoginComponent.builder().mailComponent(mailComponent).build()
```

Comment: Is there any difference between writing `@ApplicationScoped ` on top each method of Module separetly and writing it on top of @Module once?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov - Putting `@ApplicationScoped` annotation top of `@Module` will have no effect. The purpose of a module is to provide dependencies through provider methods (methods annotated with `@Provides` annotation). These providers methods may or may not have scopes. Thus it becomes important to define scopes at provider method level.