# Dagger2 component with more than one dependencies

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

This is what I currently have and it works:

```java
@FragmentScope
@Component(dependencies = {FacebookComponent.class}, 
           modules = {FragmentFacebookLoginModule.class})
public interface FragmentFacebookLoginComponent {

    void inject(FragmentFacebookLogin fragment);
}
```

Now I want to add another dependency. I changed it to this:

```java
@Component(dependencies = {FacebookComponent.class, AnotherComponent.class}, 
           modules = {FragmentFacebookLoginModule.class})
```

But now I get this error message:

> FragmentFacebookLoginComponent depends on more than one scoped
>   component

How can I solve this? How can I have more than one dependencies?

If I remove the scope from one component I get this error message:

> AnotherComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29619594/1016472

At the end I created a AppComponent with the right scope and let FacebookComponent and AnotherComponent extends this AppComponent.

FacebookComponent and AnotherComponent does not have it's own scope (I removed it).

Looks now like this:

```
@AppScope
@Component
public interface AppComponent {

}


@Component(modules = {FacebookModule.class})
public interface FacebookComponent extends AppComponent {

}


@Component(modules = {AnotherModule.class})
public interface AnotherComponent extends AppComponent {

}


@FragmentScope
@Component(dependencies = {FacebookComponent.class, AnotherComponent.class}, 
           modules = {FragmentFacebookLoginModule.class})
public interface FragmentFacebookLoginComponent {

    void inject(FragmentFacebookLogin fragment);
}
```

Comment: It **really** works? It seems a little strange to me. FacebookModule and AnotherModule provides objects scoped with @AppScope ?

Comment: @afj88 I don't know if it will work today but it worked 2 years ago

Answer (score 4):

You can't use scoped components in a dependencies array (which is quite strange I have to say), only unscoped, or one scoped + other unscoped.
But you can deceive dagger with "proxy" interfaces:

```
@Component
@Singleton
interface ComponentA {
    fun provideSomeA()
}

interface ProxyComponentA : ComponentA

@Component
@Singleton
interface ComponentB {
    fun provideSomeB()
}

interface ProxyComponentB : ComponentB

@Component(dependencies = [ProxyComponentA::class, ProxyComponentB::class])
@OtherScope
interface ComponentC
```

But in your ComponentC builder you should use proxy components implementations, which could easily be achieved with Kotlin:

```
class ProxyComponentAImpl(private val delegate: ComponentA) : ProxyComponentA, ComponentA by delegate
class ProxyComponentBImpl(private val delegate: ComponentB) : ProxyComponentB, ComponentB by delegate

componentA = DaggerComponentA.builder()...
componentB = DaggerComponentB.builder()...

componentC = DaggerComponentC.builder()
                   .componentA(ProxyComponentAImpl(componentA))
                   .componentB(ProxyComponentBImpl(componentB))
```

Works on dagger version 2.13, don't know about others

Also you could use vice versa inheritance ComponentA : ProxyComponentA to eliminate the need to create ProxyComponentAImpl, but it's not a good design choice if your ComponentA lays for example in a different gradle module

The solution was inspired by that issue discussion:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1225

Answer (score 2):

What you want to be determined to be within the `ApplicationScope` should be all defined without a scope, and linked together under the application scope only in the `ApplicationComponent` under the given scope.

For example,

```
@Component(modules = {FacebookModule.class})
public interface FacebookComponent {
    FacebookThing facebookThing(); //assuming this is with @Provides in FacebookModule with NO SCOPE
}


@Component(modules = {AnotherModule.class})
public interface AnotherComponent{
    AnotherThing anotherThing(); //assuming this is with @Provides in AnotherModule with NO SCOPE
}
```

Then you can do

```
@AppScope
@Component(dependencies={AnotherComponent.class, FacebookComponent.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AnotherComponent, FacebookComponent {}
```

After which you can do

```
@FragmentScope
@Component(dependencies=AppComponent.class)
public interface FragmentComponent extends AppComponent {}
```

Please note that unscoped providers create a new instance on every inject call. If you **need** the scoping, you should bind the modules to the same component, but components should only depend on other components with the intention of subscoping.

Answer (score 1):

Now Dagger supports a component that can depends on more than 1 scoped dependencies. Just update your dagger version to 2.27

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1414

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'
```

Answer (score 0):

Include on your module the dependency module like this:

```
@Module(includes = FacebookModule.class)
public class AnotherModule {...
```