# Dagger 2: Component depends on more than one scoped component

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm pretty new to Dagger 2. I'm trying to implement it in my Android project.
I've a `Service` which needs `GoogleApiClient`. I'm using Dagger to inject it in this service.

```
@FragmentScoped
@Component(dependencies = {NetComponent.class, RepositoryComponent.class})
public interface CustomServiceComponent {
    void inject(CustomService customService);
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient();
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, RepositoryModule.class})
public interface RepositoryComponent {
    DatabaseService getDatabaseService();
}
```

`AppModule`, `NetModule`, and `RepositoryModule` have methods marked `@Singleton @Provides`
When I build my project I get this error:

> The locationServiceComponent depends on more than one scoped
>   component: @Singleton NetComponent @Singleton RepositoryComponent

I understand my `LocationComponent` cannot depend on two `@Singleton` scoped components but I need both of them in my service and both need to be `@Singleton`.

Is there any better alternative to do the same thing?

Comment: "I understand my LocationComponent cannot depend on two @Singleton scoped components " -> Can you explain why this is not possible?

Comment: You could find an answer right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335146/4809482)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be aware that although you may have multiple components marked `@Singleton` their life cycles will follow those of the class where you retain the reference of the component.

This means if you initialise and retain your `NetComponent` and `RepositoryComponent` in an Activity it will follow the life cycle of that Activity and will not truly be an app singleton.

Hence, you probably won't need more than one `@Singleton` components in an Android app. Consider combining your two Singleton components into one component like this:

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class, RepositoryModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient();

    DatabaseService getDatabaseService();
}
```

Then make sure you retain this `@Singleton` component at Application level and make it available for use in dependent components that are initialised at the level of Fragment or Activity.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private final AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                           //modules if necessary
                           .build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }                   
}
```

Note that as long as your `@FragmentScoped` don't have any dependent components themselves, you can still create as many of these as you like.

Note that even though one single component now injects `GoogleApiClient` and `DatabaseService` you still achieve separation of concerns because these are provided in separate Dagger 2 Modules.

Comment: It's dirty this solution. You AppComponent share all modules, instead I want to be able to compose my Component from many others depending on required configurations and need of provided component. How to do that? crysis introducet well structure

Comment: @murt he's trying to provide singleton dependencies at a non-singleton scope. That won't work. You are right he needs to restructure, but he needs to group Components by scope - a single app-scoped component and then subcomponents or dependent components at the level of Activity or Fragment.

Comment: @murt you can look at some of the other answers using dependent components https://stackoverflow.com/a/40751767/5241933