# Difference between @Singleton & static @Provides in dagger2

Tags: dagger-2

May I know the difference between **@Singleton** VS **static** Provides in dagger2?

```
@Provides static User currentUser(AuthManager authManager) {
    return authManager.currentUser();
}

@Provides @Singleton User currentUser(AuthManager authManager) {
    return authManager.currentUser();
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These are very different attributes, and you can have one or the other independently. All of these are valid:

```
@Provides User currentUser(...) {}
@Provides static User currentUser(...) {}
@Provides @Singleton User currentUser(...) {}
@Provides @Singleton static User currentUser(...) {}
```

To set the stage, a `@Provides User` method says "for this Component or its dependencies, call this @Provides method every time you need a User". Typically the method will return a new instance every time, and Dagger won't save or cache the instance.

`@Singleton` is an example of a *scope*, which is a fancy way to say *lifecycle policy* or *policy for how often to create a new instance*. `@Provides @Singleton User` says "for this Component or dependencies, just call this @Provides method once, and save the result". `@Singleton` happens to be a built-in common case, but you could also imagine creating a `@UserScope` (always return the same instance for this User), or in Android a `@FragmentScope` or `@ActivityScope`.

For your specific case, you probably don't want `@Singleton`, because it would instruct your component to *save* or *cache* the value from AuthManager. If the User value may change across your application's lifetime, the Component wouldn't reflect that. (In that case you would also want to make sure to inject `Provider<User>`, which would update, rather than `User` which would not.)

Leaving scopes behind for a moment, `static` behaves exactly the way you would expect it to in Java: If a method doesn't require any instance state, you can make it `static`, and your virtual machine can call it without preparing any instance state. In your generated Component implementation, Dagger will automatically call `static` methods statically, and instance methods on the Module instance you pass into your Component; in Android this results in a sizable performance increase. Because you don't use any instance state in your `currentUser` method, it can easily be made `static`.

Further reading:

- SO: [Scopes in Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528599/1426891)
- Dagger docs: [Component](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html) (see heading "Scope")

Comment: So most of time, dependency method should be marked as `static` right? because rarely they have internal state.

Comment: @hqt Yes, bindings are rarely stateful, so `@Provides` implementations should often be `static`--especially with the appropriate use of [`@BindsInstance`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/BindsInstance.html) for instance bindings that would otherwise be state in a Module. For that matter, if your static `@Provides` method would just be `@Provides B provideB(A a) { return a; }`, skip over `static` and go straight to [`@Binds`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Binds.html) instead for the best performance.

Comment: Perhaps a noob question, but how can you apply this in Kotlin?

Comment: @Entreco Not a noob question at all! A well-regarded top-level question, in fact: [Dagger 2 static provider methods in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894218/1426891)

Answer (score 3):

With `@Singleton` annotation only one instance of User object will be created throughout the application lifecycle.

`static` on `@Provides` methods introduced recently to make the invocation of method faster by 15 to 20% as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic). There will be multiple instances of User object if we call this method multiple times.

Comment: My answer is also for dagger2, you can check out https://youtu.be/iwjXqRlEevg?t=5m9s  for more clarity

Comment: What if I have both @Singleton & static together?