# Dagger 2 static provider methods in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

With the recent versions of dagger 2 one of the improvements made are the possibility of having static provide methods. Simply so:

```
@Provides
static A providesA() {
  return A();
}
```

I was wondering how does one go about doing this in kotlin? I've tried

```
@Module
class AModule {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesA(): A = A()
  }
}
```

But I get the error message:

```
@Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule
```

I'm guessing there's something going on here with the companion object, however I'm quite new to Kotlin and I'm unsure of how one can do this. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There's also some discussion on this topic on https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/75rc85/keeping_the_daggers_sharp_square_corner_blog/do8ktb3/ there's a third option - top level functions.

Comment: This may be cause to the plugin you are using. Example, Dagger (Madrappss). But still this work.

Comment: @Enciyo I've asked this question around 4 years ago. Since then dagger has come a long way and now supports this. At the time, it didn't... hence the question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I think this should work:

```
@Module
object AModule {
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesA(): A = A()
}
```

Comment: @Fred, could you accept this answer if it solves your problem?

Comment: sorry, completely forgot about that

Comment: But having `object` wont it keep this singleton class for way too long? Just tested with memory dump, and even after killing activity and totally removing it from heap I still have my `object AModule` inside memory, not exactly what we would want to...

Comment: Wouldn't the class you have your static provider methods inside in Java stick around the same way?

Comment: @zsmb13 I have also checked it, and it didnt keep anything after activity was destroyed, module was simple class with static methods, without any fields or anything else

Comment: I do not think this solution works well, because making your AModule "object" not "class" will create a lot of singleton modules around the app, and they will exist even if you do not need this module instance any more, for example if you have screen scopes. Once you access your screen the module singleton will be created and it will be never cleaned because it is "object"

Comment: _Once you access your screen the module singleton will be created and it will be never cleaned because it is "object"_
-
Won't it be cleaned when the class-loader that loaded `AModule` gets garbage collected?

Comment: This solution is better as Jake Wharton says "_don't use `companion object` for modules. Use `object`. In that case, the instance will be unused and its initialization code will be removed by R8 and the methods will be truly static and can also be inlined just like Java._". https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900#issuecomment-410041915

Comment: @zsmb13 I can't make field injection work with qualifiers. Any idea why? https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1604

Comment: @zsmb13 I've also created an SO question about this. If you want to answer I'll mark as the correct answer. Regards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779791/qualifier-causes-dagger-missingbinding

Answer (score 61):

Although I think ***zsmb13***'s solution is better, I found another solution which works

```
@Module
class AModule {
  @Module
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesA(): A = A()
  }

  // add other non-static provides here
}
```

However, note that there will be two generated classes: `AModule_ProvidesAFactory` and `AModule_Companion_ProvidesAFactory` rather than the one `AModule_ProvidesAFactory` class for the case with an object instead of a class with a companion object

Comment: Actually, @zsmb13 's solution didn't work for me , yours did.

Comment: Glad it helped then :D

Comment: This is also nice because AModule can be abstract

Comment: what if A() needs some parameter

Comment: @RachitMishra If A() needs some parameter you should use constructor injection

Comment: The accepted answer won't work if there are both static provider methods and `@Binds` annotated methods in the module class, whereas this answer works for both cases.

Comment: This answer seems to align well with some related [Dagger documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/faq.html#why-cant-binds-and-instance-provides-methods-go-in-the-same-module)

Answer (score 22):

Now [Dagger2 (version 2.26) support `companion objects` in `@Module` annotated classes in kotlin withthouh @Module and @JvmStatic annotations](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.26)

> Better support for binding declarations within Kotlin companion
>   objects of @Module annotated classes.

**Update dagger dependencies to 2.26 version as**

```
def dagger_version = "2.26"
//dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

//If you're using classes in dagger.android you'll also want to include:
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
```

so now you can use

```
@Module
class AModule {

  companion object {

    @Provides
    fun providesA(): A = A()
  }

}
```

---

**Important**: Soon, adding `@Module` on `companion objects` in `@Module` classes will **raise an error**.

> Note: For backwards compatibility, we still allow @Module on the
>   companion object and @JvmStatic on the provides methods. However,
>   @Module on the companion object is now a no-op and all of its
>   attributes (e.g. "includes") will be ignored. `In future releases, we`
>   `will make it an error to use @Module on a companion object.`

Comment: should be the accepted answer "D, others are good but this is the latest

Answer (score 19):

A great explanation which seems to be Google-approved is at https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900

Specifically, see:

> Static provides can be achieved via @JvmStatic. There are two scenarios I see this come up:
>
> top-level `object`s

```
@Module object DataModule {   
  @JvmStatic @Provides fun 
    provideDiskCache() = DiskCache() 
}
```

> If you have an existing class
>   module, things get a bit weirder

```
@Module abstract class DataModule {   
    @Binds abstract fun provideCache(diskCache: DiskCache): Cache

    @Module   
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic @Provides fun provideDiskCache() = DiskCache()   
    } 
}
```

> The way this works is as follows:
>
> the companion object must also be annotated as @Module under the hood,
>   the kotlin compiler will duplicate those static provides methods into
>   the DataModule class. Dagger will see those and treat them like
>   regular static fields. Dagger will also see them in the companion
>   object, but that "module" will get code gen from dagger but be marked
>   as "unused". The IDE will mark this as such, as the provideDiskCache
>   method will be marked as unused. You can tell IntelliJ to ignore this
>   for annotations annotated with @Provides via quickfix

Answer (score 6):

For the static only approach, I like the solution of [zsmb13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894535/2011622).

However, I came here because I wanted to combine `@Provides` and `@Binds` within one module. 
This is not directly possible but with two nested modules (as [Omar Al Halabi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994441/2011622) pointed out).

I took a slightly different approach for combining `@Provides` and `@Binds`:

```
@Module(includes = [MyModule.Bindings::class])
object MyModule {
    @Module
    interface Bindings {
        @Binds
        fun bindA(a: AImpl): A
    }

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideB(): B = BImpl()
}
```

The differences are:

- The outer module is an object providing the static functions. This spares using the unintentional `companion object`.
- The inner module holds the abstract bindings. I can use an interface here, which spares the `abstract` modifier in both the class and the function.
- The outer module includes the inner module so I don't have to include the inner module elsewhere.

Comment: Does this work on multi bindings? I am trying to achieve similar to this but no luck.