# Dagger multibinding with a custom qualifier

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger, multibinding

I have the following interface called `SettingHandler` that is responsible for handling events related to a particular setting inside the Android app.

```
interface SettingHandler {

    fun onHandleEvent(event: SettingEvent)

    fun candleHandleEvent(event: SettingEvent): Boolean

    fun getSettingId(): SettingId

}
```

Then let's say I have the following Dagger module:

```
@Module
object SettingsModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSettingPresenter(
        view: SettingsContract.View,
        settingHandlers: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards SettingHandler>
    ): SettingsPresenter {
        //
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun provideSettingHandlerA(
        dependencyA: A,
        dependencyB: B
    ): SettingHandler {
        // 
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun provideSettingHandlerB(
        settingHandlerC: Provider<SettingHandler>
    ): SettingHandler {
        //
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun provideSettingHandlerC(
        settingHandlerB: Provider<SettingHandler>
    ): SettingHandler {
        //
    }

}
```

As you can see, nothing too special here, expect for the `SettingHandlerB` and `SettingHandlerC` provider methods. They both depend on each other, so I've decided to resolve this circular dependency using the Dagger supplied Provider class. Since I require a concrete implementation of a setting handler (`SettingHandlerC` for the `SettingHandlerB` and `SettingHandlerB` for the `SettingHandlerC`), I now need to differentiate between them. That's where a `@Qualifier` annotation comes into play. I created the following qualifier annotation to differentiate among different implementations.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class SettingHandlerType(val id: SettingId)
```

`SettingId` is basically an enumeration that contains all possible setting constants. So now my `SettingHandler`s module looks as follows:

```
@Module
object SettingsModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSettingPresenter(
        view: SettingsContract.View,
        settingHandlers: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards SettingHandler>
    ): SettingsPresenter {
        //
    }

    @Provides
    @SettingHandlerType(SettingId.A)
    fun provideSettingHandlerA(
        dependencyA: A,
        dependencyB: B
    ): SettingHandler {
        //
    }

    @Provides
    @SettingHandlerType(SettingId.B)
    fun provideSettingHandlerB(
        @SettingHandlerType(SettingId.C)
        settingHandlerC: Provider<SettingHandler>
    ): SettingHandler {
        //
    }

    @Provides
    @SettingHandlerType(SettingId.C)
    fun provideSettingHandlerC(
        @SettingHandlerType(SettingId.B)
        settingHandlerB: Provider<SettingHandler>
    ): SettingHandler {
        //
    }

}
```

And here comes the problem. Mutlibinding now does not work, because all my `SettingHandler`s are annotated with a `@SettingHandlerType` annotation and a Set that I'm injecting into the `SettingsPresenter` also needs to be annotated. However, annotating it with, for example, `@SettingHandlerType(SettingId.A)` won't work because in that case the Set will contain only setting handlers with that particular qualifier (`SettingHandlerA`, in this case). How can I construct a Set data structure using multibinding because I really don't want to provide another provider method where I'll be constructing it myself?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two different types of data: Individual handlers of type `@SettingHandlerType(/*...*/) SettingHandler` and a set of type `Set<SettingHandler>`. I think the best way would be to have each definition come with a `@Binds @IntoSet` complement.

```
@Binds @IntoSet abstract fun bindSettingHandlerA(
    @SettingHandlerType(SettingId.A) handler: SettingHandler): SettingHandler
```

Unfortunately, since you've defined this as an `object` in Kotlin, it's slightly more complicated to put the necessarily-`abstract` `@Binds` methods on the same object. You may need to pursue one of these other solutions to make that topology work with your case, including the use of a `companion object` to capture the otherwise-`static` `@Provides` methods:

- [Dagger 2 static provider methods in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894218/1426891)
- [@Provides and @Binds methods in same class Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48386794/1426891)
- [Dagger2 : How to use @Provides and @Binds in same module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46618763/1426891) (java)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly the solution I've been looking for.