# Dagger 2 @Provides can't be apply to static function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I have the following Java code which works fine

```
@Module(subcomponents = {MainActivityComponent.class})
abstract public class ActivityBuilder {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<?> bindMainActivity(MainActivityComponent.Builder builder);
}
```

When I convert it to Kotlin

```
@Module(subcomponents = [MainActivityComponent::class])
abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    companion object {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
            return application
        }
    }

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(builder: MainActivityComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<*>

}
```

I got error stating I can't have my `@Provides` on the static function.

```
error: @Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule
    public final android.content.Context provideContext(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                         ^
```

How could I fix that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894218/dagger-2-static-provider-methods-in-kotlin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the below works.

```
@Module(subcomponents = [MainActivityComponent::class])
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @Module
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
            return application
        }
    }

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(builder: MainActivityComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<*>

}
```

Comment: You don't need @Module on the companion object

Comment: Without @Module on the companion object that, the same error occurs

Comment: Hmm that is odd. I figured you need the `@JvmStatic` but not the `@Module` there

Comment: with dagger version 2.26 you do NOT need @Module on the companion object