# @Qualifier causes: [Dagger/MissingBinding] when field injecting

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm having this issue:

> ApplicationComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @... java.text.SimpleDateFormat cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

**Module**

```
@Module
abstract class ApplicationModule {

    @Binds
    @AppContext
    abstract fun application(app: App): Context

    @Module
    companion object {
        ...

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @CalendarPickerDateFormat
        fun provideCalendarPickerDateFormat(): SimpleDateFormat {
            return SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
        }
    }
}
```

**Qualifier**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CalendarPickerDateFormat
```

**Class**

```
@ActivityScope
class MyClass
@Inject constructor(
   ...,
    @CalendarPickerDateFormat private val calendarDateFormat: SimpleDateFormat
) {...}
```

Even if I add `@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)` to the **Qualifier** and change the class constructor  to `@param:CalendarPickerDateFormat`, I get the same error.

What's missing?

**Possible solution**

Adding `@JvmStatic` like:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@JvmStatic
@CalendarPickerDateFormat
fun provideCalendarPickerDateFormat(): SimpleDateFormat {
      return SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
}
```

Solves constructor injection but not field injection:

```
@Inject
@CalendarPickerDateFormat lateinit var date : SimpleDateFormat
```

Why?

NOTE: I've tried also the `@Module object class` [approach](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900#issuecomment-410041915) but I have the same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue in [google/Daggers repo](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1604) and this [PR](https://github.com/google/dagger/pull/1605) will "fix" this. Actually, this is not a bug and as **zsmb13** mentioned:

> From the official Kotlin docs:
>
> ```
> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according to the @Target annotation of the annotation being used. If
> ```
>
> there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target
>   from the following list is used:
>
> ```
>     param;
>     property;
>     field.
> ```
>
> So basically, it's because param is the default target when it's not
>   specified.

But this PR will be very helpful to avoid this situations in the future.

**EDIT**: [Dagger 2.25.2 fixes it.](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.25.2)